# Why I cannot access Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, ssl, ssl-certificate, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage to keep some files of my App. Suddenly I started to get an SSL errors on both iOS and Android platform and no idea what's the issue.

iOS :

```
NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/XXXXX.appspot.com/o?delimiter=/, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002e81440 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStr
FLTFirebaseStorage: An unknown error occurred while calling method Reference#listAll
```

Android :

```
V/NativeCrypto(16839): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xbd081f68: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
V/NativeCrypto(16839): error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242 0x9b4e9d4c:0x00000000)
W/NetworkRequest(16839): error sending network request GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXXXXX.appspot.com/o
```

Comment: *firebaser here* If this happened without any change from your side, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. Even if they don't have a solution, they track such reports and may be able to detect a local/regional problem that our probers can't.

Comment: Yes, I didn't do any update. Also when I do a VPN on my phone to another country, App works properly.

Comment: I just created a ticket but it's sunday. Do you know if there is any support for urgent cases?

Comment: Our users in Turkey sending mails, too. They cannot see the image files

Comment: I am also facing this issue

Comment: I got reply from firebase support. --->
We are aware of some issues with Cloud Storage in Turkey. We already informed our Engineers about this situation. Still it looks like the issue persists only with certain network providers. 

Few developers reported that using other networks mitigates the issue, so if possible please suggest this to your users as a temporary workaround.

Also, please share with us which ISPs you face the connection issues, we will forward this to our Engineering Team.

Comment: This topic is not programming related and is because of an outage at the service provider.

Comment: From what I understand the problem has now been addressed by the providers/ISPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to our investigations, USOM (National Cyber Incident Response Center) seems to block firebase cloud storage services. The issue is interestingly seemed to be related more with Turkish Government rather than Firebase. This explains why VPNs still work for accessing your files. ISP is blocked by the government in order not to reach storage services of google. I think someone (may be a responsible team in Google) need to reach them and illuminate that their action is weird and they should not block whole storage service for preventing an access to a file which they think is illegal..

Here you can check the block list:

https://www.usom.gov.tr/url-list.txt

you can search firebasestorage.googleapis.com, it is there.